# Is it correct to say "source to" instead of "source of"?

Tags: grammaticality, nouns, prepositions, collocation

Is it correct use *to* as preposition in the following sentence?

> Books are the best source **to** knowledge.

I have mostly seen *of* as being used with *source*, for example "source of knowledge". But I was wondering if I could use "source to" without it being a mistake.

Comment: It looks like you're trying to create a tagline that expresses your intention but is also glib.  To do that, you'll probably need to resort to already established idiomatic phrases and for better or worse, "source ___ knowledge" should use "of" or "for".  "Source *to* knowledge" does not make sense because a source doesn't take you anywhere which the "to" implies.  That's why "path to knowledge" makes sense and "source to knowledge" does not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it would mark you as a foreigner, though it would be understood.

I would say *source of knowledge*. I might also say *source for knowledge*, with a hardly different meaning

Comment: Actually I asked this because I need to use something like this as a tagline under a product name, so I think being understood shouldn't just be the criteria, it should not be just too wrong, isn't it ? Actually I need to use it like : "*___ is your ultimate source to knowledge!*". Would it be appropriate to use this way ?

Comment: just my personal problem that "*___ is your ultimate source **of** knowledge!*" doesn't look too appropriate to me. Any workarounds?

Comment: _Your ultimate source to knowledge_ would look wrong to me, and make me think it was written by a non-English speaker. Either _source of knowledge_ or another concept such as _route to knowledge_ or _guide to knowledge_.

Comment: @user01 Unless you are Jimmy Wales, I think I'd avoid this whole line of advertising altogether.  Maybe you'll be the *ultimate* source of knowledge, but I seriously doubt it. You ought to at least qualify it with some specific knowledge area.